# How do I use Celery to chain two HttpDispatchTask tasks with different URLs

Tags: python, celery

I'm trying to chain two tasks that use HttpDispatchTask, each task has it's own URL and performs a different action.

I'm not sure if the problem is the way I'm passing the URL arguments into the subtask, or the way I'm trying to collect results in the results backend... I just need a bit of guidance.

I'm set up like this:

1. I define my queue (in module cel.queues.bueller)

   ```
   from __future__ import absolute_import
   from celery import Celery

   celery = Celery('bueller', broker="mongodb://localhost:27017/tasks", include=['celery.task.http'])
   celery.conf.update(
       CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES=600,
       CELERYD_CONCURRENCY=20,
       CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "mongodb",
       CELERY_MONGODB_BACKEND_SETTINGS = {
           "host": "localhost",
           "port": 27017,
           "database": "results",
           "taskmeta_collection": "taskmeta_collection",
       }
   )
   ```
2. I call two tasks in a chain

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env python
   from cel.queues.bueller import celery
   from celery.task.http import HttpDispatchTask
   from celery import chain

   # task_a calls an audio processor
   task_a = HttpDispatchTask.subtask(
       None,
       {
           'url': 'http://example.com/operations/audio/update?format=json',
           'method': 'GET'
       },
       options={'queue': 'bueller'}
   )

   # task_b calls a video processor
   task_b = HttpDispatchTask.subtask(
       None,
       {
           'url': 'http://example.com/operations/video/update?format=json',
           'method': 'GET'
       },
       options={'queue': 'bueller'}
   )
   res = chain(task_a, task_b).apply_async()
   print list(res.collect())
   ```

The stack trace from my worker is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./task_runner.py", line 23, in <module>
    print list(res.collect())
  File "/Users/bueller/.virtualenvs/bueller-queue/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 142, in collect
    yield R, R.get(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/bueller/.virtualenvs/bueller-queue/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 108, in get
    interval=interval)
  File "/Users/bueller/.virtualenvs/bueller-queue/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 185, in wait_for
    raise result
TypeError: run() got multiple values for keyword argument 'url'
```

Thanks, any help is greatly appreciated.